# Invoking GNOME Activities overview from command line

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Is there a way to invoke the Activities view of GNOME from the Linux command line?  This is what the <kbd>Super</kbd> key invokes from GNOME. Once it is shown, I can interact with it as usual using the mouse.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The reason I'm asking: I'm viewing the desktop that I need to "send" the <kbd>Super</kbd> key into via a TeamViewer session.  TeamViewer has a way to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, but that of course is for Windows remotes, while this is pure Ubuntu-to-Ubuntu here.  Even if TeamViewer was not involved, and I was using VNC, I would have the same problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A command for GNOME versions up to GNOME 40 (that is up to Ubuntu 21.04) that causes the shell to switch to the overview is:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.show();'
```

Use `Main.overview.hide();` to close the overview, or `Main.overview.toggle();` to toggle between overview and normal view (with thanks to gatr and Marcelo Avila).

Comment: reverse action would be `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.hide();'`

Comment: toggle works as well, with: `dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();' `

Comment: How about show applications ?

Comment: @FadlyDzil, this question is about the activities overview.

Comment: Is there a way to run this in a BASH script?  When I try to do it now, I get an error.

Comment: Gnome shell has to be running for this to work.

Comment: I figured it out, I had the script formatted incorrectly, i'm just a doofus.

Comment: Not working anymore since GNOME 41, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There might be a proper command line way to interact with various GNOME Shell components (using DBus, I suppose), but a quick and dirty way is to simulate the keypress:

```
xdotool key super
```

Comment: This one worked.  The subsequent answer by vanadium has to be the correct answer because xdotool is not installed by default, and I suspect that dbus-send is installed by default. So I am forced into giving vanadium "the" answer mark. Thanks for your quick response though.

Comment: That is also the "fundamental" solution, i.e. directly communicating with the proces through the command line. The xdotool trick would work well, but is a hack - simulating keystrokes. May, moreover, not work for users that use Wayland as their displayserver.

Comment: @vanadium that's why I called it the "proper" way, but like a lot of GNOME stuff, the proper way is rather obscure.

Comment: Underrated comment. It worked and it is also easier.

Answer (score 4):

From GNOME 41 onwards you need an extension.

> As of GNOME 41, the dbus method Eval() is now restricted with MetaContext:unsafe-mode property (see this [commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/1970/diffs?commit_id=f42df5995e08a89495e2f59a9ed89b5c03369bf8)). This extension provides unrestricted Eval() dbus method for running arbitrary code in the compositor.

([*source*](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs#eval-gjs-gnome-shell-extension))

So the solution is:

1. [Install](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs#installation) the eval-gjs extension:
2. Use `--object-path /dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs` and `--method dev.ramottamado.EvalGjs.Eval`, like:

   ```
    gdbus call \
      --session \
      --dest org.gnome.Shell \
      --object-path /dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs \
      --method dev.ramottamado.EvalGjs.Eval "Main.overview.show();"
   ```

Comment: Not yet applicable on this site currently - as Gnome 41 is not yet in Ubuntu, but valuable addition for spring 2021: upvoting!

Comment: This seems to work with GNOME 42 as well, but you have to edit the metadata.json to change the version number.

Answer (score 4):

The safe answer, which doesn't rely on the `Eval()` method for GNOME > 41 is:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell --type=method_call /org/gnome/Shell org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:org.gnome.Shell string:OverviewActive variant:boolean:true
```

To exit the Activities overview, replace `variant:boolean:true` with `variant:boolean:false` in the above command.

See https://github.com/hardpixel/dash-to-plank/issues/12#issuecomment-934820153 for reference.

Comment: This answer works great for GNOME > 41 and doesn't need any additional extension to be installed. +1 ;)