# Invoking GNOME "Show Applications" from command line

Tags: gnome-shell, dbus

I'm trying to configure my touch-pad gestures in Ubuntu 19.10 and `xdotools` doesn't work properly when I switch between different keyboards layouts.

I've found in this post how to launch Activities Overview from command line.
[Invoking GNOME Activities overview from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095553/invoking-gnome-activities-overview-from-command-line/1095564).

But I would like to do the same thing with the "Applications" grid in GNOME shell.

Answer (score 6):

On gnome based systems, this will launch "Show Applications" by sending a dbus call:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.shellDBusService.ShowApplications()'
```

[image]

for toggling..

create a script with below content and bind the script with any keyboard shortcut you wish.

```
#!/bin/bash

status=`gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.overview.visible'`

if [ "$status" == "(true, 'false')" ]; then

dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.shellDBusService.ShowApplications()'
else
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.hide()'
fi
```

[image]

Comment: That works! But is there any way to make it a "toggle"? Like (for overview) dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();' ? It's usefull when using with the touchpad gestures

Comment: Ok.. Will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, Script Added for toggling ShowApplications.. have a review.. Thank You!!!